# Build configuration history in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

I'm new to teamcity and I have a question:
is there a way to check the latest changes on a specific job and who made them?
same as "job configuration history" in Jenkins

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, from the build configuration editing page there is a section down the bottom right with a "view history" link to view the audit log filtered to just this configuration:

[image: TeamCity build configuration editing page]

You can also access the history and all other audit information from the Administration section home page, then click the "Audit" link on the left. This will allow you to filter the audit information to specific projects, build configurations or by specific users.

Comment: One thing to note, It doesn't track VCS Root changes from what I've found. For example if my Co Worker Bob changes the Git Branch of a build. It doesn't get logged anywhere.

Comment: True, the audit log for VCS roots only shows it was changed (by who and when), but not a diff of the actual changes like it does for build configurations.

Comment: Do you need special permissions to be able to see this? Or is it only available in later versions? It doesn't seem to be there on our install of 8.1.5...

Comment: @ninesided you might need "View audit log" permissions granted by the default administrator role. Since my post was from 2013 I suspect this feature was in TeamCity 8.x.